# Using assert with arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, assert

part of the program I'm writing involves making a function to test assertions. This one is testing my Shift3DPoint function, which takes the first array and modifies it by adding the contents of the second array (so for example, test14 and test15 (as seen below) would result with the new test14 {6,8,0}. However, I'm confused about how I can word this in my function because it's supposed to return an array and I've only worked with doubles before for assert. Any help would be appreciated!

```
void UnitTest3D(void); //function for assertions
void Shift3DPoint (double pt[], double offset[]); 

void UnitTest3D(void){
    double test13[3] = {0,0,0};
    double test14[3] = {6,0,0};
    double test15[3] = {0,8,0};
    assert(UnitTest3D(test13, test14) ???
return;
}

void Shift3DPoint(double pt[], double offset[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    pt[i] = pt[i] + offset[i]; //changes array contents by adding corresponding ptB
  }

return;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what condition you are trying to look for. UnitTest3D() doesn't return anything, so it is difficult to see what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

`assert` is just a helper function you may or may not use. If you want to use `assert` explicitly (maybe because it aborts your program if it fails) you can write the test itself and then test it with assert. In your case, it would be that the `test14` would have an expected value. How I would treat the thing, at first sight could be:

```
void UnitTest3D(void){
    double test14[3] = {6,0,0};
    double test15[3] = {0,8,0};
    double expected_result[3] = {6,8,0};

    // Test the result after calling the function
    Shift3DPoint(test14, test15);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
         assert(test14[i] == expected_result[i]);

    return;
}
```

(note that you have the call with different arrays, but I think you get the point). You can write helper macros or more generic functions, but you get the idea.

Also, take into account that `double` values are rarely checked with `==`, as precission issues arise, so you should give some kind of epsilon, for the precission you want your calculations to be held:

```
assert ( fabs(test14[i] - expected_result[i]) < epsilon);
```

Comment: Memcmp might be easier

Comment: Well, it might be, unless you want to know which digit you're failing... Anyway, that code won't be used verbatim. Just to show the idea.